# Created a spk out of the Iron Python script, but when I execute it error:'NameError: global name 'Application' is not defined'

Tags: python, spotfire

I loaded the module as follows:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel import NotificationService
import sys
sys.path.append(ModulesService.GetResourceDirectoryPath("ABC.py"))
from ABC import orchestrate

orchestrate();
```

now the code inside orchestrate is as follows:

```
def orchestrate():
   # Notification service
   logFileName='';
   try:
    notify = Application.GetService[NotificationService]();
    notify.AddInformationNotification("Starting Upload ", "SERVER NAME: ", CONST_XYZ);
    ...
    ...
    do some work...
```

But I get Error as:

```
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\TIBCO\Spotfire\7.11.0\Modules\ABC_1.0.0.0\ABC.py", line 364, in orchestrate
NameError: global name 'Application' is not defined


IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException: global name 'Application' is not defined
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonGlobal.GetCachedValue(Boolean lightThrow)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonGlobalInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonCallTargets.OriginalCallTarget6(PythonFunction function, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, Object arg4, Object arg5)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`9.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute6[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

I have tried looking up how to Import the Application, but did not find any help.

I expect the notification from this script existing in the module to be visible on spotfire notifications.

Comment: Have you tried putting the function definition `orchestrate` directly inside the ironpython script?

Comment: Yes the orchestrate function is inside the IronPython script, which is inturn bundled as a module.

Comment: But, I mean, have you tried to put the `orchestrate` function directly inside your python script instead of inside the module? (so that the function call and function description are both inside your python script)